# Linq Query - the most inner select takes a lot of data from db and carries it across all selects

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to optimize my LINQ query to the database. At first i done everything doind linq methods.

```
Where(citizen => citizen.ID == citizenID)
                .Select(c => new CitizenSummaryInfo()
                {
                    Name = c.Entity.Name,
                    AvatarUrl = c.Entity.ImgUrl,
                    CanWork = c.Worked == false,
                    Experience = c.Experience,
                    Trained = c.Trained,
                    JobID = c.CompanyEmployee.CompanyID,
                    ID = c.ID,
                    GoldAmount = ((double?)c.Entity.Wallet.WalletMoneys
                    .FirstOrDefault(wm => wm.CurrencyID == (int)CurrencyTypeEnum.Gold).Amount) ?? 0.0,
                    HitPoints = c.HitPoints,
                    UnreadMessages = c.Entity.MailboxMessages.Count(msg => msg.Unread),
                    UnreadWarnings = c.Entity.Warnings.Count(w => w.Unread),
                    Strength = (double)c.Strength,
                    MilitaryRank = (double)c.MilitaryRank,
                    EatingSafety = c.Entity.Equipment.EquipmentItems
                    .Where(item => item.ProductID == (int)ProductTypeEnum.Bread)
                    .Count() > 0,
                    CountryID = c.Region.CountryID ?? 0,
                    CountryCurrencyID = c.Region.Country.CurrencyID,
                    CountryMoneyAmount = c.Entity.Wallet.WalletMoneys
                    .Where(m => m.CurrencyID == c.Region.Country.CurrencyID)
                    .Select(m => (double?)m.Amount)
                    .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0.0,
                     Level = c.ExperienceLevel
                }).First();
```

But sql generated from this method was pretty horrible. It had about 20 queries inside which were doing crazy stuff around.
Then I used Linq Query because it has similar syntax to SQL so i thought that it could produce less selects compared to linq methods. I was fortunately right.

This is actual code:

```
return (from citizen in context.Citizens
                    join entity in context.Entities on citizen.ID equals entity.EntityID
                    join employee in context.CompanyEmployees on citizen.ID equals employee.CitizenID into employee
                    join region in context.Regions on citizen.RegionID equals region.ID
                    join country in context.Countries on region.CountryID equals country.ID
                    join gold in context.WalletMoneys.Where(wm => wm.CurrencyID == goldID) on entity.WalletID equals gold.WalletID
                    join countryMoney in context.WalletMoneys on
                    new { WalletID = entity.WalletID, CurrencyID = country.CurrencyID } equals
                    new { WalletID = countryMoney.WalletID, CurrencyID = countryMoney.CurrencyID }
                    join warning in context.Warnings.Where(w => w.Unread) on citizen.ID equals warning.EntityID into warnings
                    join message in context.MailboxMessages.Where(m => m.Unread) on citizen.ID equals message.Viewers_EntityID into messages
                    join bread in context.EquipmentItems.Where(i => i.ProductID == breadID) on entity.EquipmentID equals bread.EquipmentID into breads
                    select new CitizenSummaryInfo()
                    {
                        AvatarUrl = entity.ImgUrl,
                        CanWork = citizen.Worked == false,
                        CountryCurrencyID = country.CurrencyID,
                        CountryID = country.ID,
                        EatingSafety = breads.Any(),
                        CountryMoneyAmount = (double)countryMoney.Amount,
                        Experience = citizen.Experience,
                        GoldAmount = (double)gold.Amount,
                        HitPoints = citizen.HitPoints,
                        ID = citizen.ID,
                        JobID = employee.Select(e => e.CompanyID).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Level = citizen.ExperienceLevel,
                        MilitaryRank = (double)citizen.MilitaryRank,
                        Name = entity.Name,
                        Strength = (double)citizen.Strength,
                        Trained = citizen.Trained,
                        UnreadMessages = messages.Count(),
                        UnreadWarnings = warnings.Count()
                    }).First();
```

It works fast so it's nice. But i have aesthetics problem with my SQL Query. The most inner Query selects a lot of information from citizen and it is carrying that information across queries to the outermost one.

This is actual SQL query:

```
SELECT
    [Limit3].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Limit3].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
    [Limit3].[C1] AS [C1],
    [Limit3].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
    [Limit3].[ID1] AS [ID1],
    [Limit3].[C2] AS [C2],
    [Limit3].[C3] AS [C3],
    [Limit3].[Experience] AS [Experience],
    [Limit3].[C4] AS [C4],
    [Limit3].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
    [Limit3].[C5] AS [C5],
    [Limit3].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
    [Limit3].[C6] AS [C6],
    [Limit3].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Limit3].[C7] AS [C7],
    [Limit3].[Trained] AS [Trained],
    [Limit3].[C8] AS [C8],
    [Limit3].[C9] AS [C9]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1)
        [Project9].[ID] AS [ID],
        [Project9].[Experience] AS [Experience],
        [Project9].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
        [Project9].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
        [Project9].[Trained] AS [Trained],
        [Project9].[Name] AS [Name],
        [Project9].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
        [Project9].[ID1] AS [ID1],
        [Project9].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
        CASE WHEN (0 = [Project9].[Worked]) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN (0 <> [Project9].[Worked]) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1],
        CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[EquipmentItems] AS [Extent11]
            WHERE ([Extent11].[ProductID] = 1 /* @p__linq__1 */) AND ([Project9].[EquipmentID] = [Extent11].[EquipmentID])
        )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2],
        CAST( [Project9].[Amount1] AS float) AS [C3],
        CAST( [Project9].[Amount] AS float) AS [C4],
        CASE WHEN ([Project9].[C1] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project9].[C2] END AS [C5],
        CAST( [Project9].[MilitaryRank] AS float) AS [C6],
        CAST( [Project9].[Strength] AS float) AS [C7],
        [Project9].[C3] AS [C8],
        [Project9].[C4] AS [C9]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Project8].[ID] AS [ID],
            [Project8].[Experience] AS [Experience],
            [Project8].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
            [Project8].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
            [Project8].[Strength] AS [Strength],
            [Project8].[MilitaryRank] AS [MilitaryRank],
            [Project8].[Worked] AS [Worked],
            [Project8].[Trained] AS [Trained],
            [Project8].[Name] AS [Name],
            [Project8].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
            [Project8].[EquipmentID] AS [EquipmentID],
            [Project8].[ID1] AS [ID1],
            [Project8].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
            [Project8].[Amount] AS [Amount],
            [Project8].[Amount1] AS [Amount1],
            [Project8].[C1] AS [C1],
            [Project8].[C2] AS [C2],
            [Project8].[C3] AS [C3],
            (SELECT
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Warnings] AS [Extent10]
                WHERE ([Extent10].[Unread] = 1) AND ([Project8].[ID] = [Extent10].[EntityID])) AS [C4]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Project7].[ID] AS [ID],
                [Project7].[Experience] AS [Experience],
                [Project7].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
                [Project7].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
                [Project7].[Strength] AS [Strength],
                [Project7].[MilitaryRank] AS [MilitaryRank],
                [Project7].[Worked] AS [Worked],
                [Project7].[Trained] AS [Trained],
                [Project7].[Name] AS [Name],
                [Project7].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
                [Project7].[EquipmentID] AS [EquipmentID],
                [Project7].[ID1] AS [ID1],
                [Project7].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
                [Project7].[Amount] AS [Amount],
                [Project7].[Amount1] AS [Amount1],
                [Project7].[C1] AS [C1],
                [Project7].[C2] AS [C2],
                (SELECT
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM [dbo].[MailboxMessage] AS [Extent9]
                    WHERE ([Extent9].[Unread] = 1) AND ([Project7].[ID] = [Extent9].[Viewers_EntityID])) AS [C3]
                FROM ( SELECT
                    [Project6].[ID] AS [ID],
                    [Project6].[Experience] AS [Experience],
                    [Project6].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
                    [Project6].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
                    [Project6].[Strength] AS [Strength],
                    [Project6].[MilitaryRank] AS [MilitaryRank],
                    [Project6].[Worked] AS [Worked],
                    [Project6].[Trained] AS [Trained],
                    [Project6].[Name] AS [Name],
                    [Project6].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
                    [Project6].[EquipmentID] AS [EquipmentID],
                    [Project6].[ID1] AS [ID1],
                    [Project6].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
                    [Project6].[Amount] AS [Amount],
                    [Project6].[Amount1] AS [Amount1],
                    [Project6].[C1] AS [C1],
                    [Project6].[C2] AS [C2]
                    FROM ( SELECT
                        [Project4].[ID] AS [ID],
                        [Project4].[Experience] AS [Experience],
                        [Project4].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
                        [Project4].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
                        [Project4].[Strength] AS [Strength],
                        [Project4].[MilitaryRank] AS [MilitaryRank],
                        [Project4].[Worked] AS [Worked],
                        [Project4].[Trained] AS [Trained],
                        [Project4].[Name] AS [Name],
                        [Project4].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
                        [Project4].[EquipmentID] AS [EquipmentID],
                        [Project4].[ID1] AS [ID1],
                        [Project4].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
                        [Project4].[Amount] AS [Amount],
                        [Project4].[Amount1] AS [Amount1],
                        [Project4].[C1] AS [C1],
                        (SELECT TOP (1)
                            [Extent8].[CompanyID] AS [CompanyID]
                            FROM [dbo].[CompanyEmployees] AS [Extent8]
                            WHERE [Project4].[ID] = [Extent8].[CitizenID]) AS [C2]
                        FROM ( SELECT
                            [Project3].[ID] AS [ID],
                            [Project3].[Experience] AS [Experience],
                            [Project3].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
                            [Project3].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
                            [Project3].[Strength] AS [Strength],
                            [Project3].[MilitaryRank] AS [MilitaryRank],
                            [Project3].[Worked] AS [Worked],
                            [Project3].[Trained] AS [Trained],
                            [Project3].[Name] AS [Name],
                            [Project3].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
                            [Project3].[EquipmentID] AS [EquipmentID],
                            [Project3].[ID1] AS [ID1],
                            [Project3].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
                            [Project3].[Amount] AS [Amount],
                            [Project3].[Amount1] AS [Amount1],
                            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1]
                            FROM ( SELECT
                                [Project1].[ID] AS [ID],
                                [Project1].[Experience] AS [Experience],
                                [Project1].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
                                [Project1].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
                                [Project1].[Strength] AS [Strength],
                                [Project1].[MilitaryRank] AS [MilitaryRank],
                                [Project1].[Worked] AS [Worked],
                                [Project1].[Trained] AS [Trained],
                                [Project1].[Name] AS [Name],
                                [Project1].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
                                [Project1].[EquipmentID] AS [EquipmentID],
                                [Project1].[ID1] AS [ID1],
                                [Project1].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
                                [Project1].[Amount] AS [Amount],
                                [Project1].[Amount1] AS [Amount1],
                                (SELECT TOP (1)
                                    [Extent7].[CompanyID] AS [CompanyID]
                                    FROM [dbo].[CompanyEmployees] AS [Extent7]
                                    WHERE [Project1].[ID] = [Extent7].[CitizenID]) AS [C1]
                                FROM ( SELECT
                                    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
                                    [Extent1].[Experience] AS [Experience],
                                    [Extent1].[ExperienceLevel] AS [ExperienceLevel],
                                    [Extent1].[HitPoints] AS [HitPoints],
                                    [Extent1].[Strength] AS [Strength],
                                    [Extent1].[MilitaryRank] AS [MilitaryRank],
                                    [Extent1].[Worked] AS [Worked],
                                    [Extent1].[Trained] AS [Trained],
                                    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name],
                                    [Extent2].[ImgUrl] AS [ImgUrl],
                                    [Extent2].[EquipmentID] AS [EquipmentID],
                                    [Extent4].[ID] AS [ID1],
                                    [Extent4].[CurrencyID] AS [CurrencyID],
                                    [Extent5].[Amount] AS [Amount],
                                    [Extent6].[Amount] AS [Amount1]
                                    FROM      [dbo].[Citizens] AS [Extent1]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Entities] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[EntityID]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Regions] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[RegionID] = [Extent3].[ID]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Countries] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[CountryID] = [Extent4].[ID]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[WalletMoneys] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[WalletID] = [Extent5].[WalletID]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[WalletMoneys] AS [Extent6] ON ([Extent2].[WalletID] = [Extent6].[WalletID]) AND ([Extent4].[CurrencyID] = [Extent6].[CurrencyID])
                                    WHERE [Extent5].[CurrencyID] = 2 /* @p__linq__0 */
                                )  AS [Project1]
                            )  AS [Project3]
                        )  AS [Project4]
                    )  AS [Project6]
                )  AS [Project7]
            )  AS [Project8]
        )  AS [Project9]
    )  AS [Limit3]
```

Personally I think that this result could be achieveable with 1 (maybe 2?) selects that have a lot of inner joins.

Does this construction of query cause performance issues?
(Personally I think that there is an issue with performance giving that SQL compared to 1 select with inner joins. But I cannot prove that. It's just my opinion.)

What Can I do to improve my query?
(Can I do anything?)

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes. I would like to not write SQL SP btw,

Comment: Is there a logic or performance issue with your query? If not then I suggest you just don't look at it!!

Comment: I think that I eliminated most issues and performance is very good. My concern is that this query will be performed on ~90% of requests so, if it can work better then it will improve user experience.

Comment: @Shoter EF can only approximate the real SQL you can write, specifically because it doesn't know all THAT much about your data and thus has to account for all possibilities; the best performance would be achieved by something like Dapper (or even with EF you can drop down to ADO.NET) where you'd write this complex query yourself and return the results.

Another thing you can try is create a SQL view with your nice query and then map it as a simple table in EF

Comment: @zaitsman thanks! I think that view may be a nice idea. I did not think about that and it is so simple :)

Comment: I'm with @Nick.McDermaid, if it performs adequately then don't worry about it. Pre-optimizing something just because the generated code doesn't look nice isn't a good use of your time.

Comment: IMO it's always good practice to examine sql that's generated by EF on complex queries like this. I'm only familiar with MS SQL so I would examine the execution plan. Missing indexes - scans vs seeks.  Depending on the size of the data - what runs fast today might not necessarily run as fast in a month.  So the due diligence in pre-optimizing in this situation I believe is justified.